# Using active directory group as netgroup in sssd

Tags: active-directory, sssd, nis

I have an active directory domain with a handful of linux servers that interact with AD through sssd.  I want to have a different sudoers configuration on different servers, and I know this can be done through netgroups.  So far, I've managed to get some servers into a netgroup by adding a nisNetgroup object in AD, and adding servers to the nisNetgroupTriple attribute on that object (and setting the ldap_netgroup_search_base option in sssd.conf). As a result, I can query the netgroup successfully on the linux servers using getent:

```
$ getent netgroup <name>
<name>         (<server>.<domain>,,)
```

Changing netgroup membership is done by modifying the nisNetgroupTriple attribute of the nisNetgroup object.  This means a user with permission to modify the object can put any server into the netgroup.  I would like to lock this down further, for example by using a standard AD group, where a user would need to have permission to modify the group and the computer account in order to add the computer to the group.  Is it possible to have sssd use a standard AD group as a netgroup?

Comment: Is the computer account in AD?

Comment: It is.  The Linux servers are all joined to the domain using the "realm join" command.

Comment: Adding a member to a group does not require permissions for the member as only the group is modified.

Comment: You're right... I just tested this and I only needed permissions for the group.  Thanks Greg.